# Embedded Tomcat: how to configure the number of request threads

Tags: tomcat, embedded-tomcat-7

In **Embedded Tomcat**, how can I configure the **number of request threads**?

I can't seem to get it to work. I tried all of these without success:

- tomcat.getConnector().setProperty("maxThreads", "20");
- tomcat.getConnector().setAttribute("maxThreads", "20");
- tomcat.getConnector().setAttribute("maxThreads", 20);

Answer (score 1):

If you want embedded tomcat to refuse new connections after 20 connections, you should also set acceptCount attribute. So, below code should work and refuse new connections after 20.

```
tomcat.getConnector().setAttribute("maxThreads", "20");
tomcat.getConnector().setAttribute("acceptCount", "20");
```

(check the introduction on http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)