# Grails how to configure the number of requests that are handled synchronously

Tags: tomcat, grails

I'm wondering where I can configure how many requests my Grails application handles at the same time. I wonder if I can configure directly the embedded tomcat in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920221/embedded-tomcat-how-to-configure-the-number-of-request-threads) way. Or is there somewhere in the Grails configs I can change the setting of this? I'm trying to configure this because I feel a significant delay when there are multiple, like 3, requests coming in at the same time.

I'm using Grails 2.4.4. My controllers are all in default scope (I didn't manually configure it as singleton or session) and my actions are all in closure format.

Appreciate your advice!

Comment: Are all the requests coming from a single browser? If so, it's most likely the browser that is limiting the number of concurrent requests to a single host. You might start by verifying that's not the issue. Grails doesn't control the number of concurrent requests. Tomcat has a maximum default of around 150. I think it's your browser.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Your point makes a lot of sense! I think it can be the cause of the problem and I'm checking it now. However, I wonder what will happen if there's no more memory or resource that Grails can assign to a new request handling thread? Will it be queued or will it just throw an exception?